# If statement defaults to true

Tags: c, if-statement, scanf

This is a simple process I wrote to try and fix a problem I'm having with other code. Can someone tell me why the if statements are defaulting to true? I read something about scanf requiring a space before the variable, but I did that.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

char answer;

printf("Y or N ");

scanf(" %c", &answer);

if(answer == 'Y' || 'y'){
   printf("you said yes \n");
}

else if (answer == 'N' || 'n'){
   printf("you said no \n");
}

else {
   printf("sorry, fail \n");
}

return 0;

}
```

It doesn't matter whether I type N or n or any other character or even number, it spits back "you said yes".

Comment: Where did you learn that `answer == 'Y' || 'y'` would work?

Comment: not entirely sure, but I swear that's how if statements deal with char's, no?

Comment: It's equivalent to `answer == ('Y' || 'y')`. What do you think `('Y' || 'y')` is equal to?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19107067/c-language-yes-or-no-if-statement-with-a-char this is where I found that, and I assumed that it means answer is equal to 'Y' or 'y'. Sorry, I'm completely new to c.

Comment: is the problem that I have to do answer == 'Y' || answer == 'y' ?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: Thanks! that was a really good way to help me see the problem. Can I ask why I need to separate the two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with the test logic.

```
if(answer == 'Y' || 'y')
```

That statement is not working like you might think.  The 'y' is netting your program a value of "true" for a lack of a better way of stating it.

What you most likely want is a comparative test like this:

```
if((answer == 'Y') || (answer =='y'))
```

Noting that correction, following is a refactored version of your program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    char answer;

    printf("Y or N ");

    if (scanf("%c", &answer) != 1)
        return 1;

    if((answer == 'Y') || (answer =='y'))
    {
        printf("you said yes \n");
    }

    else if ((answer == 'N') || (answer == 'n'))
    {
        printf("you said no \n");
    }

    else
    {
        printf("sorry, fail \n");
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Following were some tests at the terminal.

```
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/ScanTest/bin/Release$ ./ScanTest 
Y or N U
sorry, fail 
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/ScanTest/bin/Release$ ./ScanTest 
Y or N Y
you said yes 
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/ScanTest/bin/Release$ ./ScanTest 
Y or N N
you said no
```

To recap, be aware of how logical "and" and "or" operators work within the various tests ("if", "while", and so forth).